# ClassNotFoundException when running an android app

Tags: android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, egit

I'm trying to run the Spydroid app [from](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/) . But run into a "Unfortunately Spydroid has stopped" as soon as it runs on my Nexus 4.

I used egit to grab a copy of the code into a new project in eclipse. At that point, it threw out a couple errors telling me to right click on the project and select Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties. I did as it said and then hit run, which uploads it to the Nexus 4, installs it and when it attempts to run is when I get the crash.

Am I doing something wrong in the checkout/setup process?
I posted a similar post to the project's [google code page](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/issues/detail?id=92&thanks=92&ts=1364454233)

**Logcat:**

```
03-28 02:59:20.028: D/AndroidRuntime(31294): Shutting down VM
03-28 02:59:20.028: W/dalvikvm(31294): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41920930)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application net.majorkernelpanic.spydroid.SpydroidApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.majorkernelpanic.spydroid.SpydroidApplication" on path: /data/app/net.majorkernelpanic.spydroid-1.apk
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.majorkernelpanic.spydroid.SpydroidApplication" on path: /data/app/net.majorkernelpanic.spydroid-1.apk
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
03-28 02:59:20.028: E/AndroidRuntime(31294):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible error can be:

- Check the package name carefully
- Check order/export option in Build Path

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for in the order/export option in Build Path?

Comment: Hi Chris, Sorry for late reply. Order/Export is important if you are using any 3rd party library. Take an example, if you are using AdMob SDK then you have to include jar file. You need to export that jar file in build path otherwise it will give **ClassNotFoundException**